# Is there a JavaScript function the same as CFSwapInt16LittleToHost

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native

I am trying to convert some code from Xcode into React Native.

I have come accross this code:

```
    else if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:self.respCharUUID]) {
    uint16_t rpm = 0;
    
    if ((reportData[0] & 0x01) == 0) {
        rpm = reportData[1];
    }
    else {
        rpm = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(*(uint16_t *)(&reportData[1]));
    }
```

However, I do not understand what CFSwapInt16LittleToHost does except in the docs that say:

> The integer with its bytes swapped. If the host is little-endian, this function returns arg unchanged.

located [here from apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1425272-cfswapint16littletohost).

Is there a Javascript function that is the same?  If so, how would i use it?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: You said code from `xcode` but I'm fairly sure the actual language is `Swift`. Could you show some output of what those variables are? Without seeing what format JS thinks they are, and what context you're writing this code in, there's no way to know.

Answer (score 1):

Your Swift code is checking whether the number (as bytes) is big- or little-endian, and swapping little to big (if that is what the host requires).  Here's an example of how to swap big/little in JS:

[How do I swap endian-ness (byte order) of a variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320439/how-do-i-swap-endian-ness-byte-order-of-a-variable-in-javascript)

iOS is more commonly little-endian but is not guaranteed as such:

[Is iOS guaranteed to be little-endian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58614504/is-ios-guaranteed-to-be-little-endian)

However, Apple provide a function to return the endianness of the host.  You may have to write a wrapper for this in React Native.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1425298-cfbyteordergetcurrent

Android is mostly guaranteed to be little-endian (but it wouldn't hurt to check):

[Endianness of Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212951/endianness-of-android-ndk)

You can use the following Android function to check (again, you will probably have to write a wrapper for this):

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteOrder#nativeOrder()

Comment: No problem!  If it answered the question for you, please accept so it can help others.  If you solved it your own way, feel free to make your own answer and accept that.